# Cant download photos from Rebel xti to laptop

Tags: windows-7, camera

When i plug my Canon Rebel XTi SLR into my laptop and turn the camera on, it usually pops up a screen to download photos. But right now, a busy word appears on the camera screen whereas a red light would flash before and start the download.

Please help and thanks

Comment: Your question is not exactly clear.  Have you tried to restart the camera and/or verify its in the correct mode to download the pictures ( check the manual ).

Comment: @Ramhound The EOS Rebel XTi does not have a user selectable communication mode. Tt is an Auto PTP camera

Answer (score 1):

I've tried my Canon camera with cable quite a few times. I would strongly recommend you to start using the card reader.

As far as I remember, even the Cannon support recommends using the card reader

Answer (score 0):

The Canon Rebel XT 350-D (and perhaps the XTi) are vintage cameras that have lack of driver compatibility, but they have two modes with separate issues.

### Canon Rebel XT PTP Mode:

You can use PTP mode in Windows 10, but the latest firmware still has a bug that causes permanent "Busy" status while reading the CF card.

### Canon Rebel XT PC Mode:

Windows XP had a 32-bit driver to connect to the camera in PC mode, but Windows 7/8/10 do not. Therefore use a Linux operating system in PC mode (works in Ubuntu 18.04).

### How to Switch Modes

```
 Settings > Advanced Menu 2 > Communication > PC Connection
```

[image]

It's called "Normal" on the Canon 20D

[image]

BUT I noticed that when I plugged in the camera to the PC nothing popped up, so I had to use a progam like Shotwell (for Linux) or Microsoft Photos app (for Windows) to import the photos.

### Alternatives

You can bypass the firmware and driver issues by have to using an external CF Card reader (~$20 new)